# ImportError: cannot import name 'foo'

Tags: python

I'm learning python and received my first error in line 3:

here is my code:

**app.py**

```
import logging.config

from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from platform import settings

app = Flask(__name__)


def main():
    app.run(debug=settings.FLASK_DEBUG)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and my file structure is like this:

```
project_name
|--platform
|  |--api
|  |--database
|  |-- __init__.py
|  |-- app.py
|  |-- settings.py
|--logging.conf
|--requirements.txt
|--readme.md
|--setup.cfg
```

i use PyCharm IDE and execute in terminal: `python platform\app.py`
then i receive this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "platform\app.py", line 4,
>   in
>
> from platform import settings
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'settings'

any idea what's wrong here?

here is my settings.py

```
# Flask settings
FLASK_SERVER_NAME = 'localhost:5000'
FLASK_DEBUG = True  # Do not use debug mode in production

# Flask-Restplus settings
RESTPLUS_SWAGGER_UI_DOC_EXPANSION = 'list'
RESTPLUS_VALIDATE = True
RESTPLUS_MASK_SWAGGER = False
RESTPLUS_ERROR_404_HELP = False

# MYSQL settings
MYSQL_DATABASE_URI = 'blablalba'
MYSQL_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

PYMYSQL_CONNECTION = {
    'host': '123.456.789.111',
    'port': 3306,
    'user': 'root',
    'passwd': 'password',
    'db': 'database'
}
```

Comment: I guess `settings` should be a function rather than a file.

Comment: What happens if you do `python -m platform.settings`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, i run that in terminal, nothing happen, just empty newline

Comment: @AnD. That's probably the expected result if you don't have anything but a bunch of imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a package named `platform` but you are attempting to execute a script in it. When you do that, the script is going to be run independently, with none of the package information because the script is not imported. To do a proper import and then run as a script, use the [`-m`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) option:

```
python -m platform.app
```

This will import the script from the `platform` package, set up the dependencies correctly, etc.

Generally, you would want to place your executable script outside your main package for this exact reason. If you modify your folder structure to look like this, the command `python app.py` should run just fine because `platform` will be a recognized package:

```
project_name
|--platform
|  |--api
|  |--database
|  |-- __init__.py
|  |-- settings.py
|-- app.py
|--logging.conf
|--requirements.txt
|--readme.md
|--setup.cfg
```

Finally, as a minor nitpick, if you do decide to keep `app.py` at the package level rather than the project level, I would recommend using relative imports to get the settings:

```
from . import settings
```

Comment: thanks, so are you saying that, I should use: `python -m platform.app` to execute app.py? instead of `python platform\app.py` ? it is showing me good progress, but if in my: `def main()` I have `app.run(debug=settings.FLASK_DEBUG)` it will throw me `ImportError: cannot import name 'settings'` error again. if i change `app.run(debug=settings.FLASK_DEBUG)` into `app.run()` it is work well, but it make me confuse...

Comment: then how do i access settings.FLASK_DEBUG then pass it to app.run(here) ?

Comment: @AnD, where is ` main ` and what does the import look like. please post that code in your question

Comment: hi, main is in app.py - you can see my edited question - thanks for help

Comment: `settings.FLASK_DEBUG` is in import settings (settings.py)

Answer (score 0):

You have everything setup fine, my guess is that you are using `settings.py` as a constants file. so instead of

```
from platform import settings
```

try to  import the values from the file relatively (since both `app.py` and `settings.py` are in the same directory)

```
from settings import *
```

and then you can use them like

```
print(FLASK_SERVER_NAME)
```

Although this would work fine, but I like to do it a bit differently, so as to not end up scratching my head trying to figure out what constant or function comes from where. Here are my 2 cents

```
import settings.py as configs # or any variable name you want to use

print(configs.FLASK_SERVER_NAME)
# more understandable as now you know FLASK_SERVER_NAME is coming from configs
```

Comment: thanks, but i tried: `import settings.py as configs` but i received this:  `ImportError: No module named 'settings.py'; 'settings' is not a package`

Comment: Can you tell me that which directory are you trying to run from and what command you use? It is just an issue of relative paths in your case.

Comment: Hi, i run: python platform/app.py which inside platform folder

Answer (score -3):

You can straight away use `import settings` instead